# Handling exception in Lambda Expression

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8, java-stream

What will be the equivalent lambda expression for below code?

```
List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String var: alreadyList) {
     try {
         if (getNumber(var) == num) {
             filteredList.add(var);
         }
     } catch(NullPointerException exception) {
           throw exception;
     }
 }
```

- `getNumber` method throws `Nullpointerexception` and the above code is also in a method which throws the same exception to a caller.

This is usual lambda expression but how to throw the `Nullpointerexception` in it?

```
List<String> List = alreadyList.stream()
            .filter(var -> getNumber(var) == num)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The original code is strange. As you can see, it just re-throws the exception. In other words, it doesn't really do anything.

Comment: `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception and so you don't need to catch / throw it explicitly at all (and arguably shouldn't.) So the short answer is the stream based code you have is *already* the equivalent of what's above, the code above just has some needless exception catching in it.

Answer (score 3):

Catching a NPE is bad practice. NPE is an unchecked exception. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> If an argument is null, the method might throw a NullPointerException, which is an unchecked exception.

Instead why not add another filter to the stream:

```
List<String> List = alreadyList.stream()
        .filter(e -> e!= null)
        .filter(var -> getNumber(var) == num)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Agreed that Catching an NPE is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to catch NullPointerException. You can use Optional class to avoid it and do necessary action only if object is present. You can throw other exceptions from your getNumber() method without any problems

Answer (score 1):

Never catch the unchecked exceptions including the `NullPointerException`. The way you do is just rethrowing it. Either filter out the `null` values out.

```
List<String> List = alreadyList.stream()
                               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                               .filter(var -> getNumber(var) == num)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code you have provided:

```
List<String> List = alreadyList.stream()
                               .filter(var -> getNumber(var) == num)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Will already throw the `NullPointerException` in case `getNumber(var)` would fail. Your `try-catch` does not do anything different.

Comment: Is there a difference between `Objects::nonNull` and `(c -> c != null)` ?

Comment: @GBlodgett: Nope in the behavior. [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) is just a static wrapper used as a shortcut and a reference which is generally accepted standard of filtering `null` values out. See its implementation [since the line 264](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java). Moreover in `c -> c != null` you make easier an mistake forgetting the `!`.